# Is there a way to beep in the console using POWERSHELL

Tags: powershell, console, console-application, beep

I'm just starting to learn how to code in Powershell. So, how can I do dis?

I searched the MS website but it is not clear...

Comment: I mean, like, is it `[console]::beep()` or just `beep()` ???

Comment: You can also change the frequency and duration with params like this `[console]::beep(500,300)`.  The first one is frequency in hertz(ranging from 37 to 32767 hertz) and the second is duration in milliseconds.

Answer (score 10):

PowerShell has *no* dedicated command for emitting a beep.

Therefore, use [`[Console]::Beep()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Console.Beep), which you note as an option. This relies on the fact that you have virtually unlimited access to .NET APIs from PowerShell:

```
[Console]::Beep()
```

An alternative, available in Windows PowerShell v5.1 (the latest and *last* version - not sure about earlier ones) and in all versions of [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), is to use [escape sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) `` `a `` inside an [expandable string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) (`"..."`).

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine "`a"
```

Note: While `` "`a" `` alone would work too, it would also *print a newline* (which `Write-Host -NoNewLine` avoids).